# How to delete all old elements in functional component

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-component, use-ref

I need to delete all old divs with h1 after fetching:

```
export default function SearchSong() {
    const [topSongs, setTopSongs] = useState([]);
    let inputEl = useRef(null);
    const fetchData = async () => {
```

upd. Here's fetch(returns correct data):

```
      let sTrack = inputEl.current.value;
        sTrack = sTrack.replace(/ /g,"+");
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=${sTrack}&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json`
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setTopSongs(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      };
  
    return (
      <div>
<div className="inner-input">
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="search" >Search for song:
            </h1>
```

There is input:

```
            <input ref={inputEl} size="50" type="text"/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={fetchData} >Fetch</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        {topSongs?.results?.trackmatches?.track.length &&
          topSongs.results.trackmatches.track.map((datumn) => {
            return (
                <div key={datumn.name}>
                                  <h1 className='heading'>{datumn.name}</h1>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I have tried useRef and delete parent element

Comment: What old fragments? You excluded the most important part of the code. What does the `fetchData` do? How is the `topSongs` set? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: `inputEl` is used as a ref in which component?

Comment: From what I understand you want to display just the `<div className="inner-input">` when you haven't yet fetched data and just the `<h1 className="heading">` elements after you `fetchData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragments` themselves are not rendered in the actual DOM tree. You usually use them to render 2 or more elements under a single root parent. So there's no use removing them after rendering.

You can, however, remove them from the `map` function and instead

```
return <h1 key={datum.name} className="heading">{datum.name}</h1>;
```

since you're returning a single root element anyway.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to conditionally render depending on whether a statement is `true` or `false`:

```
{topSongs?.results?.trackmatches?.track.length ?
  topSongs.results.trackmatches.track.map((datumn) => {
    return (
      <div key={datumn.name}>
        <h1 className='heading'>{datumn.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
}) : (
  <div className="inner-input">
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="search" >Search for song:
      </h1>
      <input ref={inputEl} size="50" type="text"/>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={fetchData} >Fetch</button>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

The `topSongs.results.trackmatches.track.map()` will render when `topSongs?.results?.trackmatches?.track.length > 0`, otherwise the `<div className="inner-input">..</div>` will.